# In SQL, if i set a condition to null then I get 0 results

Tags: sql

I got a table which contains all the information about the artist. My wish is to retrieve the details for those artists who are deceased and calculate the age

```
select artistName, dateDeceased - dataOfBirth as Age
From my.artist
Where artistID in (select artistID from My.artist where dateDeceased != Null);
```

The problem is that I will get 0 result and when I remove the subquery the results will come out but with the artist who are still alive which I don't need.

So I believe there is something wrong with the NULL condition but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for a subquery at all:

```
SELECT artistName, dateDeceased - dataOfBirth AS  Age
FROM my.artist
WHERE dateDeceased IS NOT NULL
```

Since `NULL` is a non-value (absence of a value), you cannot use the usual comparison operators - you need to check using `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`

**Update:** as @GarethD points out - should `ArtistID` *not* be your primary key, e.g. if there could be *multiple* entries with the same `ArtistID`, of which only a few are deceased and you'd want to get all of those - then you'd need to use the subquery you already have - adapted to using the `IS NOT NULL`:

```
SELECT artistName, dateDeceased - dataOfBirth AS  Age
FROM my.artist
WHERE ArtistId IN (SELECT ArtistId FROM my.artist WHERE dateDeceased IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: This is true assuming artistID is unique, which is a fair assumption based on the table and column names, but still worth noting. If artistID is not unique a subquery would be necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You should use "IS NOT NULL" instead of "!-NULL"

Comment: No problem, but can you mark one of the answers as the answer please? Marc_S probably deserves it for explaining why.

Answer (score 2):

Just use : "IS NOT NULL" instead of "!= NULL"

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if one of them solved your problem. You are welcome!